# Android: share simple text as file/attachment

Tags: android, file, android-intent

I have an app that collects some info and allows the user to share it using Android's Intent framework.

So far, it shares the report as plain text: using `putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, report)`, where `report` is a `String`.

However, I want the report to be shared as a file, making it easy to share as an email attachment rather than the body.

Do I have to create an actual file for that purpose? If I do, it has to be in a location that other apps can read, as explained in [send binary content](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html#send-binary-content).

I was expecting an API that would allow me to provide a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, so maybe I'm just missing something. Specifically, I'd rather NOT force the sharing app to get permission to any storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to share a file that is not publicly accessible. Check out [Setting Up File Sharing](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html) for a short tutorial.

Sending text as an email attachment is a bit tricky though. You can't use `text/plain` as type because that would imply the data is supplied in `EXTRA_TEXT`. But text in this extra will end up in the email body, not in an attachment.

What should work is the following:

```
Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "org.example.provider.authority", reportFile);

Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("*/*");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, null));
```

You should also make sure that `FileProvider.getType()` returns `text/plain` for the report file. The easiest way to accomplish this is by using `.txt` as file extension and `FileProvider` will automatically do the right thing.