# Share String as file attachment in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to share a String as a file, without temporarily saving it to the filesystem? When sharing to gmail for example, it should be attached to the email.

Something like:

```
fun share(activity: Activity) {
    val content = "Col1,Col2\nABC,DEF"
    activity.startActivity(Intent().apply {
        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        type = "application/csv"
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CONTENT, content)
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CONTENT_NAME = "myData.csv")
    })
}
```

All I can find is to either share it as plain text or as file, but from the filesystem.

Comment: i found this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280228/android-share-simple-text-as-file-attachment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `ACTION_SEND` implementation that supports an "attachments" concept will probably use `EXTRA_STREAM` for the source of the attachment. That has to be a `content` `Uri`, particularly on Android 7.0+ devices.

The "out of the box" solution is to use `FileProvider` as the supplier of the content and the `content` `Uri`, and `FileProvider` requires a file.

You could create your own `ContentProvider` that implements `openFile()` and serves a string, though there is some risk of your process being terminated between your `startActivity()` call and when the other app tries using your provider.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Too bad, i was hoping for a simpler solution that does not require to create a temp file.